# (g)make subroutine or procedure?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a (g)make script that covers a lot of microcontroller targets. A sequence of if blocks test for the various targets and set (or append) a lot of variables.

```
ifeq ($(CHIP),lpc1114fn28)
   CORE_FLAGS  := -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb 
   CORE_FLAGS  += -nostartfiles -fno-exceptions 
   CORE_CPP_FLAGS  += -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-use-cxa-get-exception-ptr
   XTAL        := 12000000
   . . . 
endif
```

There is a lot of duplication, which I'd like to factor out. I tried

```
define Cortex-M0 =
  CORE_FLAGS  := -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb 
  CORE_FLAGS  += -nostartfiles -fno-exceptions 
endef

ifeq ($(CHIP),lpc1114fn28)
   $(eval $(Cortex-M0))
   CORE_CPP_FLAGS  += -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-use-cxa-get-exception-ptr
   XTAL        := 12000000
   . . . 
endif
```

But this does not seem to work. Is there a way to execute a subroutine-like construct that can contain multiple lines? I know I could use include files but I'd like to keep everything in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't working then most likely your version of GNU make is older than 3.82.  The syntax `define VARIABLE =` was introduced in that version; older versions don't allow you to use the assignment operator (`=`, `:=`, etc.)  If make sees it there it will assign a variable named, literally, `VARIABLE =` (or in your case, `Cortex-M0 =`).

Remove the `=` at the end of the `define` line and it will work with older versions of GNU make.

Remember that the online version of the manual describes the latest version of GNU make; if you're not using that version, you should be careful that the version you're using supports the features you want.  It's always safest to read the version of the manual that is provided to you along with the package of GNU make that you are using: whether it's your package manager or you downloaded it from somewhere yourself.

Comment: I think I use 3.81, and it does work when I remove the = !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

may be this:

```
ifeq ($(CHIP),lpc1114fn28)
   $(eval $(call Cortex-M0))
```

Comment: No, it doesn't :( IIRC I did try that, and a few other combinations of $(eval and $(call. $(call seems call an expression-like function, which is not what I want. From its decription $(eval should do what I want, but it does not seem to work with a multi-line variable.